# Recarregar tabela sem refresh com Ajax jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma tabela que tem a opção de atualizar registros, porem preciso que ao alterar um registro ele seja alterado dinâmico na tabela sem precisar do refresh..
já esta funcionando a parte do servidor ele já altera o dado e tals.. porem preciso dar refresh na página para poder ver a alteração realizada.. tenho o seguinte JS:

```
if(e.update){
    $('#insert_form').each(function(){
         $('.alert').removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success');
                this.reset();
         });

    // Aqui eu preciso recarregar a tabela..
    $('#employee_table') // Refresh!

}
```

esta dentro de um request, e caso o retorno seja update ele var executar a função que estiver ai dentro..

Answer (score 1):

Caso escolha por reconstruir a tabela, você poderia remover o conteúdo de `tbody` e renderizar novamente com o o retorno do jQuery ajax. Algo como:

```
success: function (result) {     
    $('tbody').empty();
    result.forEach(function(item){
       $('tbody').append('<tr><th>'+item.chave+'</th></tr>');
    })
})
```

Comment: exato, porem não existe outra forma sem precisar reconstruir a mesma?

Comment: Sim @Drik, ter um identificador único da linha da tabela e alterar as propriedades dela com o retorno.